# Using one Input data in two tasks

Tags: java

Is there a way to use one Input data in two tasks? I have a program that has to check if an Email matches a particular pattern and at the end if an email is correct the program prints it. In my case I have to write the email twice, one time so an email can be stored in a variable `email = In.readLine();` and the second time so it can be checked `vname = In.readIdentifier();` and I want to write it just once.

```
Out.print("Please enter an Email-Adress: ");
email = In.readLine();
name = In.readIdentifier();
if (!In.done()) {
    Out.println("Error : False name");
    return;
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `readIdentifier`? Are you just trying to check whether `email` is valid?

Comment: That's what the email variable is for. You must pass this variable as argument to the method that checks the email validity, instead of reading the email from the user in this method, once again.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `readIdentifier()` function so you can pass the previously read "email" variable to it instead of reading from `In` again.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to read email twice. So your custom code:

```
email = In.readLine();
name = In.readIdentifier();
```

can be changed to:

```
email = In.readLine();
//name = In.readIdentifier();
```

and further in your business logic you could just use email instead.